# Many-to-many sql select query containing multiple values, all values are taken into account

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many

There is the following database structure:

[image]

How do I write a query that returns only those Questions that have both CSS and JS tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select tq.question_id
from tagsquestions tq join
     tags t
     on tq.tag_id = t.id
where t.name in ('JS', 'CSS')
group by tq.question_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that the tags assigned to a single question are distinct.  That seems like a reasonable assumption.